# Tail-recursive function in XSLT 2.0 is not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to write a tail-recursive function in XSLT 2.0, which iterates through a multivalued variable of dates and returns the earliest one. For some reason my function is not recognized by SaxonHE9.4 as tail-recursive and I get the following error, when the input file has more than 150-200 entries or so:

> Error on line 73 of tail_rec_test.xsl:   Too many nested function
>   calls. May be due to infinite recursion.   in built-in template rule

**Here's my xml-input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Events>
  <Event>
    <Date>2004-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>2003-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>2002-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>2005-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>2006-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>2007-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>2008-01-01</Date>
  </Event>
</Events>
```

**This is what my xsl-file looks like:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:own="http://ownfunctions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:function name="own:findEarliestDate">
        <xsl:param name="dates" as="xs:date*"/>

        <xsl:variable name="size"><xsl:value-of select="count($dates)" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$size &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="own:findEarliestDate-helper($dates, $size, xs:date('2050-01-01'))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="own:findEarliestDate-helper" as="xs:date">
        <xsl:param name="items" as="xs:date*"/>
        <xsl:param name="i" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="curMin" as="xs:date"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when
                test="$i = 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="xs:date($curMin)"/>           
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="item" as="xs:date">
                    <xsl:value-of select="xs:date($items[$i])"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="next" as="xs:date">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$item &lt; $curMin">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$item"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$curMin"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:value-of select="own:findEarliestDate-helper($items, $i - 1, $next)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:template match="Events">
        <xsl:variable name="items" as="xs:date*">
            <xsl:for-each select="Event">
                <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(Date)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <Test>
            <EarliestDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="own:findEarliestDate($items)"/>
            </EarliestDate>
        </Test>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I transform it into a correct tail-recursive function?
I have tested this example, but I cannot apply it to my own code:
http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2008/02/20/EfficientXslt20RecursionInSaxon9.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I can't repro this**.

Using Saxon 9.4.06EE (evaluation copy) the result is:

```
<Test xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
      xmlns:own="http://ownfunctions">
   <EarliestDate>2001-01-01</EarliestDate>
</Test>

Saxon-EE 9.4.0.6J from Saxonica
Java version 1.6.0_31
Using license serial number XXXXXXXX
Generating byte code...
Stylesheet compilation time: 2168 milliseconds
Processing file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xml
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Building tree for file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xml using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 10 milliseconds
Tree size: 27 nodes, 80 characters, 0 attributes
Execution time: 122ms
Memory used: 52169472
NamePool contents: 8 entries in 8 chains. 6 URIs
```

**BTW, one can use just this to produce the same result**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="min(/*/*/Date/xs:date(.))"/>
```

---

**Update**:

The problem is in this line:

```
            <xsl:value-of select="own:findEarliestDate-helper($items, $i - 1, $next)"/>
```

Because the return type of the function is `xs:date`, the above line isn't the last line in the execution sequence of the function. It produces a *string* (more precisely, a text node), and the XSLT processor needs to get this string and to convert it to an `xs:date` -- that means that the memory ocupied by the function isn't discarded and the call-stack continues to grow, until it overflows.

**The solution is simple**:

Replace the above with:

```
            <xsl:sequence select="own:findEarliestDate-helper($items, $i - 1, $next)"/>
```

This produces an `xs:date` and the XSLT processor now recognizes the function as tail recursive.

**I tested the corrected code with 1000 events (on which the original code crashes) and the result is produced normally (and faster).**

```
Saxon-EE 9.4.0.6J from Saxonica
Java version 1.6.0_31
Using license serial number XXXXXXXXXX
Generating byte code...
Stylesheet compilation time: 2002 milliseconds
Processing file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xml
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Building tree for file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xml using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 124 milliseconds
Tree size: 3032 nodes, 9800 characters, 0 attributes
Execution time: 364ms
Memory used: 55089048
NamePool contents: 8 entries in 8 chains. 6 URIs
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply (+1)! I tested the short version and it is definitely efficient enough (works great with 5000 Events). Although it would be nice to know why my function is not behaving as a tail-recursive one. It stucks at 150-200 Events, but this probably depends on the VM heap size. Could you please try with lots of Events? I could update the input, but it would be huge. Just say what you prefer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ivo, I found your problem and updated my answer with the problem, its explanation and an easy solution.

Comment: Do try to break the habit of using "xsl:value-of". Every time you write this, you should ask yourself whether xsl:sequence would be more appropriate. The xsl:value-of instruction creates a text node; in this example you are converting a date to a text node which is then converted back to a date.